# parse JSON from PHP file to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to parse json data from php file to javascript file
the json object data is parsed and tested but when i want to access to specific element in the object, I faced problem undefined in the alert.

PHP file contains

```
[{"userID":"2","username":"abdo","password":"abdo","flag":"1","status":"1","typeID":"2"}]
```

the code:

```
                login: function() {
                var usr = this.get("username");
                var pass = this.get("password");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: {username: usr, password: pass},
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data) {

                        alert(data[0].username);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('fail');
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. Also it would be better to copy-paste the error in the question (as code block) and to mention that error in the title.

Comment: Try `json[0].username`.

Comment: The code formatting is still horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `[array]` at the top level.
And `data` is a JSON object *already*, no need to parse it again.
It means you have to do : `alert(data[0].username)`

Comment: it give me in the browser consol

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o index.html:247
$.ajax.success index.html:247
c jquery-1.9.1.js:7341
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:7403
k jquery-1.9.1.js:9597
n.onload.n.onreadystatechange

Comment: Try doing just `alert(data[0].username)`